# Why I get errors when I try to out a compiler defined macro using a pragma message?

Tags: visual-studio, preprocessor, pragma

I would like to know why the Visual C++ compiler gets me an warning/error if I use the following code:

```
#pragma message( "You have " _MSC_FULL_VER )
```

Here is what I get:

```
error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
warning C4081: expected ':'; found ')'
```

The problem reproduces for `_MSC_FULL_VER` or `_MSV_VER` but not if I try to use others like `__FILE__` or `__DATE__`.

These macros are defined, they are documented on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `#pragma message` needs C strings only. IIRC, `_MSC_FULL_VER` is a number, while `__FILE__` and `__DATE__` are C strings. Try this

```
// BEWARE! Untested macro hackery ahead!
#define STRINGIFY( L )       #L
#define MAKESTRING( M, L )   M(L)
#define STRINGIZE(X)         MAKESTRING( STRINGIFY, X )
#pragma message( "You have " STRINGIZE(_MSC_FULL_VER) )
```

(On a side note, this allows

```
#define SHOWORIGIN            __FILE__ "(" STRINGIZE(__LINE__) "): "
#pragma message( SHOWORIGIN "your message here" )
```

which allows you to double-click on a message in VS's output pane and be taken to its file/line.)